# Python Tools for Visual Studio can't download `setuptools` on IronPython

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ironpython, ptvs

I'm using *PTVS 2.1* with *IronPython 2.7.4* in *Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop* with Update 3 on a *Windows 8.1 Pro x64* host with .NET 4.5 installed. I have an empty Python project with default env set to *IronPython 2.7*. When I want to a virtual environment to the project PTVS tries to download *setuptools* and *pip* and fails miserably. The full [log of the operation is here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fckYLSEU). In a gist it fails with:

```
System.IO.IOException
"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."
```

The `IOError` seems to be thrown when invoking the `urlopen` function. I've modified the sources so it tries downloading packages though `http` as well as `https`, but both gives same exceptions. PTVS executes everything without problems when working within official Python 2.7.8 environment.

I'm stuck with this problem. I can't install *setuptools* for IronPython through PTVS. Script provided in instructions at [*setuptools'* PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) also uses `openurl` and fails with the same error.

Is there a way to install/use `setuptools` within IronPython env?

Comment: try 2.7.5b3, as Administrator you can `ipy -X:Frames -m ensurepip`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the tip and for the work on the project itself. Maybe you could add an answer with an explanation why that worked, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

once 2.7.5 will be released, it will include a back port of ensurepip. Installing pip and setuptool is as simple as invoking:

```
ipy -X:Frames -m ensurepip
```

At the moment you can use 2.7.5b3 as a best approximation.
Older versions of IronPython may work with some older versions of setuptools or pip but the record is spotty.