# Install pip for IronPython on commandline

Tags: python, pip, ironpython, easy-install

Is it possible to install and use pip with IronPython via the commandline? (I am not doing this via PTVS.)

Things I have tried already:

- Looked at this SO question: [Installing Python Packages - IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433684/installing-python-packages-ironpython), but it hasn't been answered or updated for more than a year.
- Looked at this answer [on Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120131104149AA7f3XS), but the link to `distribute_setup.py` is broken. I got a copy from here: [distribute_setup.py](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsvn.apache.org%2Frepos%2Fasf%2Foodt%2Ftools%2Foodtsite.publisher%2Ftrunk%2Fdistribute_setup.py&ei=qLtYVI4y5LPuBrvngZgD&usg=AFQjCNESMeEWIZnuRYUWsrLyzc5m60X7ww&sig2=Un_voWqfnzPvwyNO_XYhUw), it terminates with this:

  ```
  IOError: System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  ```
- Taken a look at the [pip docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#id7), but this is obviously for CPython, not IronPython.
- Followed the steps on [Steps to installing setuptools on IronPython](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=setuptools). According to the comments, it worked in August last year, but I got the same error as above:

  ```
  IOError: System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  ```
- Taken a look at the full output of these errors. It seems to pick up the egg, but fails later on in the process during a call to `urllib2.urlopen(url)`:

  ```
  Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ez_setup.py", line 158, in download_setuptools
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 512, in http_response
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 432, in error
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 619, in http_error_302
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 411, in _open
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1168, in do_open
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 955, in request
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 1158, in connect
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ssl.py", line 366, in wrap_socket
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ssl.py", line 133, in __init__
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ssl.py", line 295, in do_handshake
    File "ez_setup.py", line 278, in <module>
    File "ez_setup.py", line 210, in main
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 989, in _send_request
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 773, in send
  IOError: System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  ```

Any ideas on what else to try, or if this is likely to work at all?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663366/python-tools-for-visual-studio-cant-download-setuptools-on-ironpython

Comment: Thanks @PawelJasinski! I had tried that, but not with IronPython 2.7.5b3. I guess this question should be marked a duplicate, but I don't think I have the rep to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I installed regular (CPython) on my hard drive and had my IronPython Engine setsearchpaths [Importing external module in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371994/importing-external-module-in-ironpython) to its Lib and Lib\site-packages directories.   I could then install packages into CPython and use them in my IronPython scripts.   This may not work for every package though.